# Zpl.batch print job - How to cut on each label

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using a print job with native ZPL with the same label and many copies using `^PQ` command. I need the labels to be cut one by one, but what is happening is the cut is only occurring after the last label is printed. How do I set the cut to be done on each label individually?
The Cutter mode was activated using the `^MMC` command.

Comment: Please provide us with the code, else we will not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `^PQ` command like this:

```
^PQx,1,0
```

Parameter 1 (x): Replace x with the quantity of copies to be printed.
Parameter 2 (1): activates print pause and cut after each lable
Parameter 3 (0): no replicates of serial numbers

[Reference](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)